# Replace letters for in factor variable and eliminate spaces

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm trying to clean my data for processing. I have a column (factor variable) that contains time information in the following format:
`1H 35MIN 37SEG`

Before I proceed to convert this into time, I'd like to convert all my observations from the above format, I need to eliminate the letters and the spaces, such that I have all my observations like this instead:
`1:35:37`

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` and regular expressions.   I included `as.character` to convert your factors to strings.

```
Times = c('1H 35MIN 37SEC',  '1H 35MIN 37SEC', '2H 40MIN 19SEC')
gsub("\\D+", ":", gsub("\\D+$", "", as.character(Times)))
[1] "1:35:37" "1:35:37" "2:40:19"
```

The first substitution removes trailing non-digit characters. Then the second substitution changes any remaining non-digit characters to colons.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want to do with it later, but if you want to be able to treat it like a time period in calculations, the lubridate package will do all of it for you with hms

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
lubri_time <- hms("1H 35MIN 37SEG")
# to convince yourself that this is actually an object that can be used in time calculations:
unclass(lubri_time)
# [1] 37
# attr(,"year")
# [1] 0
# attr(,"month")
# [1] 0
# attr(,"day")
# [1] 0
# attr(,"hour")
# [1] 1
# attr(,"minute")
# [1] 35
```

That first value (37) is the number of seconds. It works the same way with `"1H 35MIN 37SEC"` if `SEG` was a typo in your question